# Por que mi sitio web html no muestra algunas de mis imagenes y videos?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un proyecto de portfolio en html en el cual muestro varias imagenes y videos. Algunas si se visualizan, sin embargo otras no, y la forma de declararlas en el codigo es la misma, tienen formatos y tamanos similares, no existe mucha diferencia.

Esta es la declaracion de la imagen que SI se visualiza:

```html
<div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12 cat3">
<div class="single-portfolio">
<div class="images">
<a href="assets/images/portfolio/cw7.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Cate Webs contact">
<img src="assets/images/portfolio/cw7.jpg" alt="portfolio">
</a></div></div></div>
```

Esta es la declaracion de la imagen que NO se visualiza:

```html
<div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12 cat2">
<div class="single-portfolio">
<div class="images">
<a href="assets/images/portfolio/chat.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="ChatBot Javascript responsive">
<img src="assets/images/portfolio/chat.jpg" alt="portfolio">
</a></div></div></div>
```

Y bueno ya los videos si no se ve ninguno que tampoco entiendo por que? :

```html
 <div class="grid-item col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12 cat1">
    <div class="single-portfolio">
    <div class="images">
    <a href="assets/images/portfolio/mapa.mp4" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="ProcessMapGraph in Canvas">
    <video src="assets/images/portfolio/mapa.mp4" type="video/mp4" alt="portfolio" controls></video>
    </a></div></div></div>
```

[Aquí está el sitio con las imagenes que no se muestran](https://elizabthpazp.lovestoblog.com/portfolio.html)

Comment: No parece que se muestren porque no estan... si te fijas, las unicas cosas que hay en esa carpeta de portfolio las veras aqui:  https://elizabthpazp.lovestoblog.com/assets/images/portfolio/  y no hay muchas que digamos, quizas tienes un limite y no suben bien

Comment: Para las imágenes que no se muestran, el servidor responde con `https://infinityfree.net/errors/403/`. Eso es _acceso prohibido_. Falta configurar algún permiso ;)

Comment: Probe tu codigo con mis imagenes y funciono, como te indican revisa los permisos y revisa bien las rutas. Te recomiendo cambiar el formato de las imagenes a .webp